# Check the validity of dynamically added forms on angularjs controller's $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

To check the validity of a form in my page, I test this property in my controller's scope:

```
$scope.formName.$valid
```

The problem is that when I add forms dynamically to the page (based on a model property), the $scope.newFormName property is not added to the scope.

[This plnkr illustrate the problem](http://plnkr.co/edit/QA6jBitNLp4et2EcVAw8?p=preview)

1. Click the 'Add form' button to add forms to the page
2. Click the 'Search forms' to update the list with the forms found in the $scope
3. Note that the added forms are not found in the scope

Is there any way to make this work? How can I check the validity of this dynamically added forms?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1404?source=cc

Comment: similar issue, same principal.  you should add your plnkr to that issue so it get some attention as well.

Comment: Just did it, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

So your code adds a list of identical forms. And you want to see whether this list is valid or not.

The solution is to use `ngForm`s within a parent form. See this [Plunkr (my modified version of yours)](http://plnkr.co/edit/IYpGwJHvVwn7nJElMOY8?p=preview).

- Form input values are bound to objects in the `$scope.dynamicData` array, which also is used by `ngRepeat` to create the list of forms.
- Invalid *fields* are shown with a solid red border, and invalid *forms* have a dashed red border.

When forms are nested like this, the parent form is invalid when any of its child forms are invalid.

Comment: A while back, [I actually wrote a blog entry about this so I could remember it](http://www.benlesh.com/2013/03/angular-js-validating-form-elements-in.html)

Comment: @blesh, it was actually your article that taught me this! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `angular.element()`. I would also personally get it via ID rather than name, but that is just me. View this plunker to see what I did: http://plnkr.co/edit/b87HJt

I'm using `angular.element()` to get the element by the name, `getElementsByName` and then using the `$attr` directive to get at the name.

Comment: Although the example was misleading, the question was how to check the validity of the form (through the property `$valid`). I don't think I can access the `$valid` property through the `angular.element()`, right? I updated the original plnkr to add the validity check.